# Changing Authentication Logic for Openerp GTK client

Tags: odoo

After spending a couple of weeks on Openerp again, I tried to change the logic for openerp authentication , via WebClient on Windows 7 Machine with some logic changes in login method of rpc.py file and it worked. Now on clicking Login button Openerp reads my file instaed of database tables to authenticate. Now I would like to implement the same thing with OpenERP GTK Client. I tried hard but failed. So can any one tell me where i can make change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just out of curiosity, can u elaborate on why you need to achieve this? anywhose, i think the best place to start for the gtk client is from the client source with **/bin/environment_info.py** as well as **/bin/rpc.info**

Comment: I want to hide the database field from the login screen and user will enter login and password to enter his database, each user is having a seperate database. when he will enter username and password, i will check which database to load.

Comment: Actually I am trying to customize Openerp as SAAS (software as a service) , where different users can have their own Sales, Purchase, Warehouse Etc. and they cant see each others data or even database name.

Comment: sounds as if you'd have a completely separate environment including addons and database, more like a server for each user? i must say this is the first time ive heard of such thing

Comment: You are absolutely right, but isnt it a good Idea, and can you answer my Question..?

Comment: i dont think this would be a good idea. you would be pretty limited to the number of users and end up with plenty of duplicate environments. i suggest u invest some time im achieving your goal via the user access rights and openerp security. it would be far more logical. concerning your question, i thought i did answer it. changing the rpc.py in the server makes what you want doable with the web client seeing that the web server is a core module, but the gtk-client is standalone and you need to modify its code as well. u can find rpc.py and environment_info.py in the client source.

Comment: Thanks A lot for your This point, Actually that is a bit of what I was looking for, I will consider your suggestion, and let you know if it worked for me. By access rights and security can i make it for 500 users, each user having his data only viz sales orders, customers, suppliers, products, they may have same products or they may also have same customer, etc etc